# Is that possible to bind and move an element with mouse movement on Angular 7th Drag and drop feature without clicking the element?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a div element that will move horizontally in accordance to mouse movement, on Angular 7.

I've embedded the [new drag and drop feature](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) but the movement is click dependant.

Is there a way to use the new drag and drop feature but make it non click-dependent?

The purpose is to move the token at the upper part of the screen in a connect-four game.

[image: 1]

This is the entire Html for the feature:

```
    <app-token cdkDragLockAxis="x" cdkDrag></app-token>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Have you tried using angular/cdk's drag and drop module?